# Ubuntu 18.04 - How can I ignore offline DNS servers?

Tags: dns, vpn, ubuntu-18.04

My case is as follows:

While at office, I use site-to-site VPN and my DNS servers are part of the office domain, which can be accessed only through the VPN.

While at home, I can connect to point-to-site VPN and DNS is working just fine.

The problem occurs while not connecting to the VPN in either way. I'm using systemd-resolved and my first 2 DNS servers are the domains servers, while the rest of the DNS servers can be reached without VPN.

Every request is sent to the first 2 servers, waiting for their response and since they are unreachable, it will take a few seconds for each request to reach a working DNS server.

My question is, can I set the system to ignore unreachable DNS servers for defined time before trying them again?

Comment: Does your system have manually configured IP address?

Comment: No, the IP is received by DHCP, but the DNS is manually configured.

Comment: 1. Are DNS servers used over demand-dial VPN the same asones used when you are on site-to-site VPN? 2. Are those VPN servers used only to resolve internal domain names?

Comment: 1. Yes, same 2 DNS servers
2. Yes, they resolve only "example.com" domain

Answer (score 0):

You can use work around with simplest script. If your VPN is off just change DNS. like this for example.

```
status=$(systemctl is-active --quiet service "your vpn site-to-site.service" && echo "running" );

if [ "$status" != "running" ]
then
     "put your command here to change DNS when VPN is OFF"
else
     "put your command here to change DNS when VPN is ON"
fi
```

Of course you can also checking current DNS settings to prevent no needed
the same changes in file if you will use cron for example.

I can help you with this script, but I need to see your
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf first. Of course without original IP

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it and update asap.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS settings should also be dynamically configured. If (for whatever strange reason) that is not possible, you have two options:

1. You can do some tweaking in your `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding line

   `options timeout:1`

   This will make internal resolver wait max. 1 second for answer before trying the next nameserver (default value is 5)
2. Install local DNS server, preferably lightweight one like [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) or [unbound](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/). Configure it to forward requests for "example.com" to your internal DNS servers, and all other requests to default (public) DNS servers. Configure your OS resolver to use local DNS server.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. I have already tried the first option, and it did improve the experience, but it was still too slow (many websites will have to load a few more addresses so the resolve time is not really 1 or 2 seconds). I'm aware of the second solution, have not tried it yet, but was hoping to avoid it by configuring the systemd-resolved to ignore the unreachable servers. If there is no way to achieve that, I will give a shot to dnsmasq/unbound and update your answer accordingly.